# Cygwin terminal crashes

Tags: cygwin, windows-7-x64

I installed Cygwin on windows 7 64 bit ultimate and after starting cygwin terminal it crashes and creates a file named mintty.exe.stackdump, and in this file there is a line i.e

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=61004DF6
```

After searching it on google; it seems that this exception occurs if their are two cygwin1.dll in system. There is only one that is inside the installation directory of cygwin.

I had installed mingw, but even after uninstalling mingw it still crashes. I didn't worked on cygwin before can anybody guide me how I could get rid of this problem

Answer (score 0):

`cygwin1.dll` gets installed by some other programs that get ported from Linux to Windows, such as OpenSSH. It's possible that you have another version of it somewhere else on your system that was installed by a different application.

It doesn't necessarily need to be in your Cygwin install dir either. Just being in a directory that's in your `PATH` env variable, for instance, would be enough for it to cause confusion for Cygwin.

If you know exactly of a likely culprit (think Windows ports of traditionally Linux programs and tools), I would check those first. Otherwise, try digging in the different directories in your `path` var (you can see them by firing up a `cmd.exe` terminal and running the command `echo %path%`).